# Has Apple completely dropped support of the COM API for iTunes?

Tags: itunes, windows

Apple used to provide a COM-based SDK for iTunes on Windows. This could be found via https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ and a search for `iTunes COM`. It appears as if the download has been removed.

The API hasn't been updated in years, so pulling it from the download section makes sense.

Is there any official communication from Apple, that the iTunes COM API has been discontinued?

#### Update

Apple started distributing iTunes via the Microsoft App Store. It seems that  the version distributed there does not allow COM communication at all, because of sandboxing. An official confirmation would be appreciated.